# Changes in admin panel are not updating

Tags: magento, configuration, magento-1.9

I am trying to update the configuration of my Magento store. It shows me a message that the configuration was updated, but when I check the setting again, they are not updated. I thought the config file might not have permission to update, so I checked in app > etc > local.xml and app > etc > config.xml, and they have 644 permission. I changed that to 744 and still I am facing the same issue.

I want to enable template hints and for that I need to update configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some things :

1) Try delete cache from var folder : `rm -rf var/cache/*`

2) Also you can do reindex by system > index management > Rebuild all indexes

3) try in private window.....

4)check you are making changes in correct store view.....

Answer (score 0):

644 Permission is alright if you want to enable path hint from backend configuration:-

Please visit on following screenshots:-

a- https://s.nimbus.everhelper.me/share/1261238/rgwi8o8kboh66q4kkewm

b- https://s.nimbus.everhelper.me/share/1261240/1h4w6ha7x57kz7goswcn

Note:- If still, you're getting the problem, you can install path hint extensions.

e.g-  http://www.magepsycho.com/easy-template-path-hints.html